# How to put data in pointer filed using parse.com android

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com android sdk. I am working on USER table in which i have to store the value of pointer from another table , for example Object ID from UserInfo table in info column in USER table. For Current User i can easily get and set values by using ParseUser object like:

```
final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        String currentUserId = user.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        String currentUserFirstName = user.getString("firstName");
        String currentUserLastName = user.getString("lastName");
        String currentUserEmail = user.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        String currentUserContactNumber = user.getString("contactNumber");
```

Kindly tell me how to save my ObjectID from UserInfo table in info column in USER table .

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already have the info column added as a Pointer to UserInfo

set pointer

```
user.put("info", ParseObject.createWithoutData("UserInfo","$userInfoId"));
```

get pointer

```
ParseObject userInfo = user.getParseObject("info");
```